# I found this code in an autoconf configure script what is the following code trying to do?

Tags: bash

I found this code in an autoconf configure script. What is the following code trying to do?

```
if ${am_cv_autoconf_installed+:} false; then :
$as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of stuff going on here. Let's break it down.

First of all, the syntax `${var+foo}` is a common idiom for checking whether the variable `var` has been defined. If `var` is defined, then `${var+foo}` will expand to the string `foo`. Otherwise, it will expand to an empty string.

Most commonly (in bash, anyway), this syntax is used as follows:

```
if [ -n "${var+foo}" ]; then
   echo "var is defined"
else
   echo "var is not defined"
fi
```

Note that `foo` is just any arbitrary text. You could just as well use `x` or `abc` or `ilovetacos`.

However, in your example, there are no brackets. So whatever `${am_cv_autoconf_installed+:}` expands to (if anything) will be evaluated as a command. As it turns out, `:` is actually a shell command. Namely, it's the "null command". It has no effect, other than to set the command exit status to `0` (success). Likewise, `false` is a shell command that does nothing, but sets the exit status to `1` (failure).

So depending on whether the variable `am_cv_autoconf_installed` is defined, the script will then execute one of the following commands:

```
: false
```

-OR-

```
false
```

In the first case, it calls the null command with the string `"false"` as an argument, which is simply ignored, causing the `if` statement to evaluate to true. In the second case, it calls the `false` command, causing the `if` statement to evaluate to false.

So all this is really doing is checking whether `am_cv_autoconf_installed` is defined. If this were just an ordinary bash script and didn't require any particular level of portability, it would have been a lot simpler to just do:

```
if [ -n "${am_cv_autoconf_installed+x}" ]; then
```

However, since this is a configure script, it was no doubt written this way for maximum portability. Not all shells will have the `-n` test. Some may not even have the `[ ]` syntax.

The rest should be fairly self-explanatory. If the variable is defined, the `if` statement evaluates to true (or more accurately, it sets the exit status to `0`), causing the `$as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6` line to execute. Otherwise, it does whatever is in the `else` clause.

I'm guessing `$as_echo_n` is just the environment-specific version of `echo -n`, which means it will print "(cached) " with no trailing newline. The `>&6` means the output will be redirected to file descriptor `6` which presumably is set up elsewhere in the script (probably a log file or some such).